# How can I export my game to my custom ratio?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am using unity 2019.1 my game's ratio is 3:5 and custom ratio is 600:1000 but while exporting it the game comes in full screen which I don't want can you tell what is the correct option to export my game with my custom ratio?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.

1. From the code

   ```
   void Start () 
   {
       if (Screen.fullScreen)
       Screen.fullScreen = false;
   }
   ```
2. From the settings

   Edit->PlayerSettings->Player->Desktop->Resolution and Presentation->Fullscreen mode-> Windowed
   [image]

Comment: Once the game has been played or built in a different resolution and aspect ratio, making these changes has no impact. How is this fixed?

Comment: @Confused If you look at the screenshot below you can find that there is a tab "Supported Aspect Ratios" this might help, but I don't really understand your question and what is the issue. You can also change window size by `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`

Comment: Any and all of these means do not work once the game has been built once.

Comment: Something in the way Unity manages the storing of these values means that they can't be overwritten/changed once they're used. This is a long standing, well known problem. Without a work around. It seems the OP is having troubles with this issue.

Comment: If you start a new project, and change the build settings or set these values in your code, and then build... it works. Now try to change these values, and build again. You'll see that your changes are not recognised.

Comment: btw, this is a Mac problem, much more than a Windows problem. It may have been fixed in the last couple of years on Windows.

Comment: it is definitely not fixed on a Mac. Just checked.

Comment: In the question, it is not stated what platform it's an issue on so please ask another question with this mentioned. If this is a bug for mac and you need a workaround, I would crop the camera to proper aspect-ratio and add black bars around it (letterboxing)

Comment: There is a horrific way to "fix" this, which is to delete the Library folder. This requires three things: 1 that you remember every single setting in your project, as they're all lost, and 2 Unity completely rebuilds the project, which can take quite a long time for a bigger project, 3 losing some prefab and script references, which is a NIGHTMARE!

Comment: It would appear, in 2019.1, that he is hitting this exact bug, regardless of Windows or Mac. He's not getting any result to his changes to aspect ratio and sizes. That's THIS bug.